# git:listing files that ever contained specified text

Tags: git, git-log

I need to list all the files that currently or at some point in history contained a specified text.Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with:

```
git grep 'the specified text' $(git rev-list --all)
```